# Question about%pcrel_hi and %pcrel_lo for qemu virt machine

Tags: assembly, virtual-machine, qemu, bootloader, riscv

In qemu/hw/riscv/boot.c:riscv_setup_rom_reset_vec, the brom code is fixed.

```
void riscv_setup_rom_reset_vec(MachineState *machine, RISCVHartArrayState *harts,
                               hwaddr start_addr,
                               hwaddr rom_base, hwaddr rom_size,
                               uint64_t kernel_entry,
                               uint64_t fdt_load_addr)
{
    int i;
    uint32_t start_addr_hi32 = 0x00000000;
    uint32_t fdt_load_addr_hi32 = 0x00000000;

    if (!riscv_is_32bit(harts)) {
        start_addr_hi32 = start_addr >> 32;
        fdt_load_addr_hi32 = fdt_load_addr >> 32;
    }
    /* reset vector */
    uint32_t reset_vec[10] = {
        0x00000297,                  /* 1:  auipc  t0, %pcrel_hi(fw_dyn) */
        0x02828613,                  /*     addi   a2, t0, %pcrel_lo(1b) */
        0xf1402573,                  /*     csrr   a0, mhartid  */
        0,
        0,
        0x00028067,                  /*     jr     t0 */
        start_addr,                  /* start: .dword */
        start_addr_hi32,
        fdt_load_addr,               /* fdt_laddr: .dword */
        fdt_load_addr_hi32,
                                     /* fw_dyn: */
    };
    if (riscv_is_32bit(harts)) {
        reset_vec[3] = 0x0202a583;   /*     lw     a1, 32(t0) */
        reset_vec[4] = 0x0182a283;   /*     lw     t0, 24(t0) */
    } else {
        reset_vec[3] = 0x0202b583;   /*     ld     a1, 32(t0) */
        reset_vec[4] = 0x0182b283;   /*     ld     t0, 24(t0) */
    }

    /* copy in the reset vector in little_endian byte order */
    for (i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE(reset_vec); i++) {
        reset_vec[i] = cpu_to_le32(reset_vec[i]);
    }
    rom_add_blob_fixed_as("mrom.reset", reset_vec, sizeof(reset_vec),
                          rom_base, &address_space_memory);
    riscv_rom_copy_firmware_info(machine, rom_base, rom_size, sizeof(reset_vec),
                                 kernel_entry);
}
```

The brom memory layout like below:

```
------------------ --0x1000
|   reset vec    |
------------------ --0x1028
| fw_dynamic_info|
------------------

It can verify with gdb.
(gdb) x/32xw 0x1000
0x1000: 0x00000297      0x02828613      0xf1402573      0x0202b583
0x1010: 0x0182b283      0x00028067      0x80000000      0x00000000
0x1020: 0x87000000      0x00000000      0x4942534f      0x00000000
0x1030: 0x00000002      0x00000000      0x00000000      0x00000000
0x1040: 0x00000001      0x00000000      0x00000000      0x00000000
0x1050: 0x00000000      0x00000000      0x00000000      0x00000000
0x1060: 0x00000000      0x00000000      0x00000000      0x00000000
0x1070: 0x00000000      0x00000000      0x00000000      0x00000000
```

The first and second instruction is below:

```
        0x00000297,                  /* 1:  auipc  t0, %pcrel_hi(fw_dyn) */
        0x02828613,                  /*     addi   a2, t0, %pcrel_lo(1b) */
```

In https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/RISC_002dV_002dModifiers.html

```
%pcrel_hi(symbol)
    The high 20 bits of relative address between pc and symbol. 
%pcrel_lo(label)
    The low 12 bits of relative address between pc and symbol.
```

I think t0 should be zero because `%pcrel_hi(fw_dyn) = (0x00001028 - 0x00001000) >> 12 = 0x0`
But after I execute the first instruction`1:  auipc  t0, %pcrel_hi(fw_dyn)`, t0 is 0x1000 rather than 0x0.

```
0x0000000000001004 in ?? ()
(gdb) i r
ra             0x0      0x0
sp             0x0      0x0
gp             0x0      0x0
tp             0x0      0x0
t0             0x1000   4096
```

and after executing the second instruction addi `a2, t0, %pcrel_lo(1b)`,
a2 is 0x1028, the result is expected if t0 is zero.

```
0x0000000000001008 in ?? ()
(gdb) i r
ra             0x0      0x0
sp             0x0      0x0
gp             0x0      0x0
tp             0x0      0x0
t0             0x1000   4096
t1             0x0      0
t2             0x0      0
fp             0x0      0x0
s1             0x0      0
a0             0x0      0
a1             0x0      0
a2             0x1028   4136
```

Comment: `pcrel_hi(fw_dyn)` is zero, but the specific purpose of `auipc` is to add it to the `pc` which is `0x1000`.

Comment: You are genius, I got it.

Comment: AUIPC (add upper immediate to pc) is used to build pc-relative addresses and uses the U-type format. AUIPC forms a 32-bit offset from the U-immediate, filling in the lowest 12 bits with zeros, adds this offset to the address of the AUIPC instruction, then places the result in register rd.

Comment: So it don't change the pc and than save pc value to t0.

Comment: Since the code and data are close together, there's no adjustment of the pc needed to capture the upper 20 bits of the address of interest.  FYI, the formula you have `%pcrel_hi(fw_dyn) = (0x00001028 - 0x00001000) >> 12 = 0x0` is for computing the immediate value to encode in the `auipc` instruction, not for computing the result of executing that `auipc`, which is that formula in reverse, solved for the address (and would be `0x00001000 + (0x0 << 12) = 0x1000`.  You can tell which formula is used at build time (the one with subtraction) and which is used at runtime (the one with addition).